# Passing query variables to the ContentProvider in Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm wanting to know what the correct way of passing parameters for a Database query using the ContentProvider pattern is.

Is it as follow - i.e. where & args in the update method.

```
getContentResolver().update(uri, cv,where, args);
```

Or is it by appending the values at the end of the URI - As in this example in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating.html#ContentURI) - see case 2?

```
 public class ExampleProvider extends ContentProvider {
 ......
 ...... 
    // Implements ContentProvider.query()
 public Cursor query(

    Uri uri, String[] projection,String selection, String[] selectionArgs,
    String sortOrder) {

    switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)) {

       case 1:
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(sortOrder)) sortOrder = "_ID ASC";
            break;

        case 2:
            selection = selection + "_ID = " uri.getLastPathSegment();
            break;
```

And which of these approaches is the best. I've seen both used, but unsure of their respective merits.

Comment: Well, the ID is special, just as it usually is in REST-style Web service APIs. That usually goes in the `Uri`, but then only if you are querying specifically against that one individual instance represented by that `_ID`-laden `Uri`. For queries against collections, usually the `Uri` just identifies the collection and the `selection` controls the subset of rows that you get back. But, at the end of the day, it's really up to whoever implements the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer @CommonsWare -I'll ponder over your answer :)